# UIAlertView Will not show

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a program that is requesting a JSON string. I have created a class that contains the connect method below. When the root view is coming up, it does a request to this class and method to load up some data for the root view. When I test the error code (by changing the URL host to 127.0.0.1), I expect the Alert to show. Behavior is that the root view just goes black, and the app aborts with no alert. No errors in debug mode on the console, either. Any thoughts as to this behavior? I've been looking around for hints to this for hours to no avail. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Note:** the conditional for (error) *is* called, as well as the UIAlertView code.

```
- (NSString *)connect:(NSString *)urlString {
NSString *jsonString;

UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

NSError        *error = nil;
NSURLResponse  *response = nil;
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
NSData *_response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: req returningResponse: &response error: &error];

if (error) {
    /* inform the user that the connection failed */
    //AlertWithMessage(@"Connection Failed!", message);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oopsie!" 
                                                    message:@"Unable to connect! Try later, thanks."
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
} else {
    jsonString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:_response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}

app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

[url release];

return jsonString;
```

}

Comment: I figured it out...I did't realize that showing the alert isn't modal. Therefore, the underlying code does not stop, and it was throwing an error, and dying. I got it addressed. Thank you to everyone who suggested answers.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if ( error )` with `if ( ! _response )`.

`NSURLConnection`'s `sendSynchronousRequest`  documentation:

....
*error*
Out parameter used if an error occurs while processing the request. May be NULL.

**Return Value**
The downloaded data for the URL request. Returns nil if a connection could not be created or if the download fails.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change it. However, to be clear, the conditional **does** get called, as well as the UIAlertView code. It just aborts.

Comment: Ah, ok. The reason for this can be your jsonString variable. It's uninitialized and you're returning it in both cases (fail, success). Try to replace your first line with 'NSString *jsonString = nil;'.

Answer (score 0):

Does UIWindow already exist when [alert show] is called? UIAlertView show should insert alert in the view hierarchy, but if there's no window/root view yet, there's nowhere to insert it into so [alert release] just releases it prematurely.